# Create postgres replica container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-volume

In production, I have a primary database and a [read replica](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/features/read-replicas/) database.

If you're unfamiliar with this setup, the read replica is essentially a copy of the primary database. That is, all writes are made to the primary database. Then, the writes are asynchronously replicated to the read replica. So the data in the primary database and the read replica should be an exact match (pending a few second lag).

I'm trying to create this configuration locally using docker so I can debug some issues. I've come up with the following `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
services:
  db-primary:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  db-read-replica:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - '5433:5432'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

This is close to what I need but not perfect. I believe the volume is copied into the container at startup time (aka `docker compose up`) so writes to `db-primary` are not copied to `db-read-replica` after the containers are created. I need to create new containers for the changes to sync.

Is it possible to create a postgres container that is a real-time copy of another postgres container?

Note, it would be nice to disable writes (aka `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements) on the read replica container but that's not a hard requirement.

Comment: You can of course set up streaming replication between two containers. There's no magic to it - you configure them correctly, make sure connections are allowed and run a base-backup to set things up. There are quite a few examples and tutorials online. Is there something in particular that has caused you problems? Because you've not shown any configuration or errors.

Comment: @RichardHuxton Per above the problem is: "writes to db-primary are not copied to db-read-replica after the containers are created"

Comment: I don't see anything there that sets up streaming replication. You'll need to post another question showing the problem with your replication setup or if you haven't done any setup then like I said read some tutorials online.

Answer (score 0):

Streaming replication maintains a copy of another PostgreSQL cluster. The standby cluster disables independent writes on the read replica. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION